# How to install Hyperledger composer-playground?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I have been trying to install it using the below link:
https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/
Can anyone help me out with this?
I have to submit a project using Hyperledger Fabric and Composer.

Comment: It's really concerning that you are being advised to use hyperledger composer. It's only limited value now is an introduction to digital assets for educational purposes. It has no value in understanding hyperledger fabric or blockchain in general (as the concept of digital assets doesn't exclusively require a blockchain to implement). To learn about digital assets within a hyperledger fabric context you should use the samples provided at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.
Hyperledger composer is end of life, only the source code and npm modules currently remain around

Comment: As a follow on, that link was for the online playground. This has been removed. There is no online playground anymore. The composer documentation still exists (for now) here https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest however given that a lot of the resources have been taken away things described in the documentation are not going to work anymore

Answer (score 2):

Just in case people find this question, it should be noted that Hyperledger Composer is no longer actively maintained or supported.  Most of the base programming model functionality was added to the various SDKs via a higher level API abstraction.